# How do I call a method when the iPhone has signal in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

Due to the nature of my application (tracks signal) there is high probability that the application will be utilised when the device currently has no cellular signal.

How can I ensure that the method below will run once the phone recognises that it has signal?

I would still like the data to be posted but with no further interaction from the user after the initial action press that calls the method.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

        NSLog(@"Location: %@",newLocation);
        CLLocation *curentLocation = newLocation;

        if (curentLocation != nil) {

        // Code below uses a third party utility to submit data (Parse framework)
        PFObject *Object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Issue"];
        Object[@"Latitude"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        Object[@"Longitude"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Object[@"Signal"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_avgNumber];
        [Object saveInBackground];

        // Update Text Fields
        self.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",curentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.signal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_avgNumber];

    }
        // Stop the Location Update
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Apple provided a sample application to track user's connectivity: [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)